# Foundation 5 on rails 4, application.scss is after foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I have a rails 4 application with foundation 5, I've made it using the guide on Zurb's site.
I want to customize foundation, but the problem is that `application.css.scss` is linked before foundation, so my changes won't overwrite foundation.
I wanted to use foundation manually, instead of `foundation:install`
what should I do if I don't want to do that?

### edit

My fault, I should have put `require self` after `require foundation_and_overrides`

works like a charm now

Comment: Can you post here your application.css.scss file?

Comment: no, I've changed it too much so that it temporary works (styled ids instead of classes), I just want to know that is there anyway to put this application.css.scss after foundation.scss or not, and if there isn't, what should I do? :(

Comment: There is nothing important in it, some changes to dropdown for example, background-color, etc.

Comment: You should post it as an answer, not edit the question